# Дефект локализации в списке ревизий

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Один больше проблема машинной локализации участником @VladD

Под ссылкой https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/539191/revisions следующий текст может быть найден:

[image: Вася]

Это сорт нестандартного перевода. Соответствующей языковой норме могла бы быть

> за **удаление сообщения** проголосовал Вася

и

> за **удаление сообщения** проголосовали Вася, Петя, Машенька, Дух сообщества

Comment: Ох этот специфический юмор переводчиков. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На данный момент сделал так:

1. Единственное число `**$historyType$** участником $voters$`.
2. Множественное число `**$historyType$** участниками $voters$`.

Comment: Теперь сообщение будет, по идее, выглядеть так: «**Сообщение удалено** участником **Федя**», что, вероятно, не вполне правильно? Т. к. участники не удалили сообщение, а лишь голосовали? С другой стороны, возможно, тонкостями можно пожертвовать?

Answer (score 3):

### результаты розысков в *transifex-е*

фраза (на данный момент) не имеет множественных форм:

- [tx:1198](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40262883) `**$historyType$** by $voters$` → `за **$historyType$** проголосовали $voters$`

---

а `$historyType$`, судя по всему, взят отсюда:

- [tx:986](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40262658) `Post Deleted` → `Сообщение удалено`

---

схожие (но неподходящие) фразы:

- [tx:1513](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40263218) `Post is deleted.` -> `Сообщение удалено.`
- [tx:8316](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/79591988) `post deleted` → `сообщение удалено`

Comment: Проблема ещё и в том, что в форме единственного числа важен ещё и род. «За удаление сообщения проголосовал Оля» выглядит не очень. (Притом у нас в профиле нету этой информации.)

Comment: @VladD, можно без глагола: «за удаление сообщения: тот-то«.

Comment: Хм. Как-то не очень по-русски получается. :-\

Comment: @VladD, моё дело предложить. вообще, насколько помню, вопрос о родовых формах в интерфейсе уже обсуждался. и, если мне не изменяет память, решили: не морочить себе голову по этому поводу.

Comment: Ну это да, давайте подождём, может ещё варианты подкинут.

Comment: @VladD, а кто-то разве спешит? процесс добавления множественных форм в код сайта — совсем не быстрый.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin [Добавили множественные формы](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/91410336?key=e7e4bdf7e809e03c6a380dbd22f2bdb1).